# sdc1 exists but does not show under /dev/

Tags: centos, disk, fdisk, block-device, volume

I am currently working on CentOS 6.9 (Kernel Version 2.6.32-696.3.2.el6.x86_64). I have added a supplemental disk to the Virtual Machine and I can see it listed under `/dev` as `sdc` (`/dev/sdc`). When I create a partition on the disk I get `/dev/sdc1`. This is visible under `lsblk` as shown:

```
[root@testvm002 ~]# lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb                      8:16   0   40G  0 disk
└─sdb1                   8:17   0   40G  0 part /mnt/resource
sda                      8:0    0   30G  0 disk
└─sda1                   8:1    0   30G  0 part /
sr0                     11:0    1  628K  0 rom
sdc                      8:32   0   50G  0 disk
└─sdc1                   8:33   0   50G  0 part
sdd                      8:48   0   50G  0 disk
└─vg_data (dm-0) 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /data
```

and for `fdisk`:

```
[root@oratest612 ~]# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000eb274

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1        6528    52427776   83  Linux
```

However, `sdc1` does not appear under `/dev` for reasons unknown to me. Therefore, my question is why is not appearing and how do I fix it?

```
[root@oratest612 ~]# ls -lrt /dev/sd*
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  0 Oct 31 14:00 /dev/sda
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  1 Oct 31 14:00 /dev/sda1
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 16 Oct 31 14:00 /dev/sdb
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 17 Oct 31 14:02 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 32 Oct 31 14:40 /dev/sdc
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 48 Oct 31 14:40 /dev/sdd
```

Comment: Have you rebooted the node?

Comment: Yeah; rebooted and no difference. It’s still not showing under /dev

Comment: Run this command `cat /proc/partitions` and edit your question with the output. It shows what the kernel can see.

Comment: I suspect you don't have devtmpfs in `findmnt /dev`, so you rely on udev to create device nodes, but it has crashed or something.  if this is systemd you could look in the journal for error messags relating to udev.

Comment: lsblk is presumably looking in /sys, I expect the the /proc interface will show exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Then create it manually:

```
# mknod /dev/sdc1 block 8 33
```

Comment: That's fine but shouldn't it automatically create /dev/sdc1 when I create the partition as shown in fdisk? My question is geared towards understanding why this hasn't happened automatically and how it can be rectified so it is done automatically.

Comment: Yes, it should. It's probably a bug, fill a bugreport: https://bugs.centos.org/